# How can I use fetch API to upload string data as a *.json file to an endpoint that expects form data that is pointing to a local file?

Tags: reactjs, curl, fetch-api

I want to update a Json file hosted on a 3rd party CDN using their API. In their docs they provide an example how to do this using cURl. A proper cUrl request should look like this:

```
curl -X PUT 'https://endpoint.url.here' \
  -H 'x-auth-token: <token>' \
  -F 'file=@"path/to/your/file"'
```

Now I'm building a React page where you can type your Json text into a text field and once you press a button I want to simulate that I have a json file with a path that I can put into this request.

I basically have to problems:

1. I'm pretty restricted to using the Fetch API, how would I build a Fetch request to properly reflect the example cUrl request?
2. How do I convert my string from the textfield into a filepath (preferably that ends with a file name) so that the endpoint will accept it?

I've tried converting my file data into a Blob and using the object url as path like so:

```
const file = new Blob([jsonText], {type: 'text/plain'});
var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

And I've tried to set up my request using FormData:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', blobURL);

let headers = {
        'x-auth-token': '<token>',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }

let payload = {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: headers,
        body: formData
    }

fetch('https://endpoint.url.here', payload) ...
```

When I try this the backend just replies with errors like "no file provided" and I suspect my request doesn't adequately match the requirements. Is there a better way to do this? Do you have any suggestions I can try to better match their example request?

Answer (score 2):

Right, I managed to resolve my own problem. These small modifications are what made the trick:

```
const jsonBlob = new Blob(['<jsonText>'], {type: 'application/json'});

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', jsonBlob, 'filename.json');

const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('x-auth-token', '<token>');

let payload = {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: headers,
    body: formData
}

fetch('https://endpoint.url.here', payload) ...
```

Everything works like a charm now!